# Get Node and Edge data from visNetwork graph

Tags: r, graph, shiny, vis.js

I am trying to get the nodes/edges data from my visNetwork graph. I am using the example code, but it is not working. I am trying to do this with Shiny. My goal is to get the nodes and edges data from the network and then display it in a table. I will greatly appreciate any help that I can get.
Thanks,

Here is my code:

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$network_proxy_nodes <- renderVisNetwork({
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = "green")
  })


  output$edges_data_from_shiny <- renderPrint({
    if(!is.null(input$network_proxy_get_edges)){
      input$network_proxy_get_edges
    }
  })

  observe({
    input$getEdges
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_get") %>%
      visGetEdges()
  })

  output$nodes_data_from_shiny <- renderPrint({
    if(!is.null(input$network_proxy_get_nodes)){
      input$network_proxy_get_nodes
    }
  })

  observe({
    input$getNodes
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_get") %>%
      visGetNodes()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
     visNetworkOutput("network_proxy_nodes", height = "100%"),
           verbatimTextOutput("edges_data_from_shiny "),
           verbatimTextOutput("nodes_data_from_shiny"),
           actionButton("getNodes", "Nodes"),
           actionButton("getEdges", "Edges")
  )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with the code is that the name of the network `output$network_proxy_nodes` was not the same everywhere.

This is a working piece of code to get edge information and display it in plain text, and to get node information and display it as a DataTable:

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                      name = c("first", "second", "third"), 
                      extra = c("info1", "info2", "info3"))
  edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3), id= 1:2)

  output$network_proxy <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges)
  })


  output$nodes_data_from_shiny <- renderDataTable({
    if(!is.null(input$network_proxy_nodes)){
      info <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(input$network_proxy_nodes), ncol = dim(nodes)[1],
                        byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      colnames(info) <- colnames(nodes)
      info
    }
  })
  output$edges_data_from_shiny <- renderPrint({
    if(!is.null(input$network_proxy_edges)){
      input$network_proxy_edges
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$getNodes,{
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy") %>%
      visGetNodes() 
  })

  observeEvent(input$getEdges, {
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy") %>%
      visGetEdges()
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network_proxy", height = "400px"),
  verbatimTextOutput("edges_data_from_shiny"),
  dataTableOutput("nodes_data_from_shiny"),
  actionButton("getEdges", "Edges"),
  actionButton("getNodes", "Nodes")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was able to get this code to work. Best, SB

Comment: You're welcome @AquieJo ! If it worked for you, you can accept it as "the best answer" (so that it appears the green tick on the left of the answer and other people knows it answers your question).