# Get selected Node data from visNetwork graph without actionButton

Tags: r, graph, shiny, vis.js

I used the example given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905061/get-node-and-edge-data-from-visnetwork-graph) but I would like to adapt it to display the data of the node that has been selected (not all the node but only this one) and also not use the action button so that the data are displaid as soon as I click on the node.

I have tried many solution without success.

When I create my graph, I upload a CSV file and associate other parameters to the nodes (size, title ...). Would it be possible to display these parameters also when I select a node :

nodes$company_name

nodes$company_postcode

nodes$amount.size

...

Here is the code I used to start with, kindly given by @xclotet

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                      name = c("first", "second", "third"), 
                      extra = c("info1", "info2", "info3"))
  edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3), id= 1:2)

  output$network_proxy <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges)
  })


  output$nodes_data_from_shiny <- renderDataTable({
    if(!is.null(input$network_proxy_nodes)){
      info <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(input$network_proxy_nodes), ncol =     dim(nodes)[1],
                        byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      colnames(info) <- colnames(nodes)
      info
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$getNodes,{
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy") %>%
      visGetNodes() 
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network_proxy", height = "400px"),
  dataTableOutput("nodes_data_from_shiny"),
  actionButton("getNodes", "Nodes")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display data of the node selected, you can adapt the example given in [visNetwork Shiny webpage](http://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/shiny.html). In that example, `hoverNode` option of `visEvents` is used to get information of the *hovered* node.

To get the *selected node id* one can use:

```
visEvents(select = "function(nodes) {
            Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes.nodes);
            ;}")
```

This function sets the id of the node (`nodes.nodes`) to `input$current_node_id`. Then, you can use this information to display only the information corresponding to that node (by subsetting the data.frame).

Below, the example provided adapted to answer the question:

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                      name = c("first", "second", "third"), 
                      extra = c("info1", "info2", "info3"))
  edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3), id = 1:2)

  output$network_proxy <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
      visEvents(select = "function(nodes) {
                Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes.nodes);
                ;}")
  })

  output$nodes_data_from_shiny <- renderDataTable( {
    if (!is.null(input$current_node_id) && !is.null(input$network_proxy_nodes)) {
      info <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(input$network_proxy_nodes), 
                                ncol = dim(nodes)[1], byrow = T),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      colnames(info) <- colnames(nodes)
      info[info$id == input$current_node_id, ]
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$current_node_id, {
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy") %>%
      visGetNodes() 
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network_proxy", height = "400px"),
  dataTableOutput("nodes_data_from_shiny"),
  actionButton("getNodes", "Nodes")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I need.
I just encounter a problem as my node array has 1000 lines and when I click on a node I get the warning message : "value 'ncol' incorrect (too big ou NA).

Comment: You are welcome, @Jpc However, if this answer solved your question, it would be great that you clicked the green tick on the left of the answer for others to know that this works.

Comment: Btw, @Jpc did you manage to fix the warning you got? If not, could you provide more details on that?

Answer (score 3):

Offering up another suggestion, as the one above did not seem to work as elegantly:

```
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                      name = c("first", "second", "third"), 
                      extra = c("info1", "info2", "info3"))
  edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3), id = 1:2)

  output$network_proxy <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
      visEvents(select = "function(nodes) {
                Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes.nodes);
                ;}")
})


  myNode <- reactiveValues(selected = '')

  observeEvent(input$current_node_id, {
    myNode$selected <<- input$current_node_id
  })

output$table <- renderDataTable({
    nodes[which(myNode$selected == nodes$id),]
})

output$dt_UI <- renderUI({
  if(nrow(nodes[which(myNode$selected == nodes$id),])!=0){
    dataTableOutput('table')
  } else{}

})


}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network_proxy", height = "400px"),
  dataTableOutput("nodes_data_from_shiny"),
  uiOutput('dt_UI')
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

offering a other version that i found more simple if interessted

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                      name = c("first", "second", "third"), 
                      extra = c("info1", "info2", "info3pp"))
  edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3), id = 1:2)
  output$network_proxy <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
      visEvents(select = "function(nodes) {
                Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes.nodes);
                ;}")
  })

  output$nodes_data_from_shiny <- renderDataTable( {
      info <- data.frame(nodes)

      info[info$id == input$current_node_id, ]

  })

  observeEvent(input$current_node_id, {
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy") %>%
      visGetNodes() 
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network_proxy", height = "400px"),
  dataTableOutput("nodes_data_from_shiny")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```